# Fluent Nhibernate mapping hasMany

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

In my MSSQL I have two tables, Property and Photo.

To make it shorter I will write here just few fields.
Property table

```
Id int not null
Title nvarchar(255) not null
PhotoId int not null
```

Photo table

```
Id int not null
ImageData varbinary(MAX) null
ImageMimeType varchar(50) null
```

Relationship is as follows:

FK_Property_Photo

```
Primary Key table        Foreign key table
--------------------------------------------
Photo                    Property
--------------------------------------------
Id                       PhotoId
```

As you can imagine one property can have one or many images. One image can belong to one or meny properties.

I Tried with this kind of mapping

```
public PropertyMap()
{
  Table("Property");
  Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
  Map(x => x.Title).Length(255).Not.Nullable();
  HasMany(x => x.Photos).KeyColumn("Id");
}

public PhotoMap()
 {
    Table("Photo");
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Version);
    Map(x => x.ImageData).CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Length(160000);
    Map(x => x.ImageMimeType);
 }
```

Comment: Which side do you want the association to appear on? I'll have a look at the fluent docs, I prefer the xml mappings myself :S.

Comment: How do you associate multiple photos with one property? Is there a 'link' table you didn't mention?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to make use of [References and HasMany](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#references--many-to-one) associations. You are already using HasMany, so to get the other association:

```
public PropertyMap()
{
  Table("Property");
  Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
  Map(x => x.Title).Length(255).Not.Nullable();
  HasMany(x => x.Photos).KeyColumn("Id"); // you were already doing this
}

public PhotoMap()
 {
    Table("Photo");
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Version);
    Map(x => x.ImageData).CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Length(160000);
    Map(x => x.ImageMimeType);
    References( x => x.Property ) // you'll need 'Property' in your class definition too
        .Column('PhotoId')
        .Cascade.All();
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome. Now I might just understand fluent mappings when I see them. :)